# Rails notifications system 2018

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to build a notifications system in Rails and almost all of the questions on the subject are a little old now.

It will be fairly simple at first, sending notifications for expired documents, but in the future should be able to notify based on dates, non-existent records, event occurrence, lack of event occurrence, etc. It will also require stop components, ending notifications once a new document is collected, or when an expected record is entered. The notifications will be in-app, but will expand to include email, SMS, and possibly other formats. I also want admins to be able to configure the notifications, controlling who is notified, how often, by what method, whether they recur, on what event, and what the notification says.

In terms of gems, the most recommended from the other questions came in the form of Activity Notification. It seems like a fairly comprehensive solution though I am a little concerned that it relies deeply on the Public Activity gem, which doesn't seem to be kept updated much these days. Has anyone using Activity Notification found this to be a problem at all? Has anyone had any issues that would prevent them from recommending Activity Notification?

The other option I've seen discussed is Notifications, though I'm reluctant to use it as it doesn't seem to be very well documented.

Would anybody who has used either of these gems say there's an argument to be made for building the system from scratch?

Any advice at all is welcome, thank you.

Comment: Building your own [sounds exciting](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-6OK2CgfysNQ/U86JhcS_OKI/AAAAAAAAurI/O5lNezASrwo/s1600/10373729_294545550713169_1314239177487458186_n.jpg)! :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev 